# Jaydata with requirejs

Tags: requirejs, jaydata

I am getting the following error while using require.js with Jaydata:

```
 $.data is not defined
```

---

Here,is my code..

```
$data.Entity.extend("schedule_common", {
    'ScheduleCommonId'  :  { key:true,type:'int',nullable:false,required:true  }

});
```

I have written at the top of my file

```
require(['jaydata','datajs','inmemoryprovider'], function($){
    return {...........
....................}
});
```

Kindly suggest me a way!!

Answer (score 1):

I modified the jaydata source and made it work

I just commented the 'amd' and the 'module' lines

```
(function(mod) {
      //if (typeof exports == "object" && typeof module == "object") return mod(exports); // CommonJS
      //if (typeof define == "function" && define.amd) return define(["exports"], mod); // AMD
      mod(self.acorn || (self.acorn = {})); // Plain browser env
    })(function(exports) {
      "use strict";
      ...
```

after that in the config :

```
 require(["jaydata", ...
     function ($data) {
          window.$data = $data;
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

require.js isn't supported in JayData yet, but I've found some community requests here (AMD supporT) - [JayData backlog](http://jaydata.org/backlogs)